Feasibility of Using Xinya XY2500 4-Pin Pluggable Terminal for Three-Phase PCB
I am designing a PCB for a three-phase system and considering using the Xinya XY2500 4-pin pluggable terminal connector (pitch 5.08 mm, rated 15A @ 300V) to connect R (Phase 1), Y (Phase 2), B (Phase 3), and N (Neutral). My concerns are whether this connector can safely handle the voltage requirements:

Is the 300V rating sufficient for typical three-phase voltages, especially considering peak values?
Are the creepage and clearance distances provided by the 5.08mm pitch sufficient for safety and compliance with standards such as IEC and UL?
Additionally, if there are other factors I should consider or alternative connectors you recommend, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Thank you!


What do you mean by "typical three-phase voltages"? That could be anything from 120/208 V to many thousands of volts.

Line to line 440V

The fact that 440 > 300 should be all the answer you need then, even ignoring that the peak voltage is higher.

An addendum from the asker in the comments stated that the voltage under consideration is "Line to line 440V".
To that, I respond: The fact that 440 > 300 should be all the answer you need, even ignoring that the peak voltage is higher.
While it may function just fine, you are using the part far outside its ratings, and as such you can't assume it will be safe under these conditions. It probably won't violently explode, but it may quietly break down over time and fail short a few months after you put it into active use. And there's no guarantee it won't somehow violently explode anyway.

Thanks for the reply. Could you please recommend alternative connectors for 440Vac?
